# Javascript Find by this OR/ELSE find by this

Tags: javascript, find

Is there a cleaner way to find the first value in an array that matches a condition and if that value isn't found, try a different value?

```js
const animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'snake'];

let favoriteAnimal = animals.find(animal => animal === 'cat');

if (!favoriteAnimal) favoriteAnimal = animals.find(animal => animal === 'dog');
```

Updated my question a bit. If 'cat' isn't in the array, then look for 'dog'. If 'cat' or 'dog' are not found, just return *undefined.*

Comment: what are you expecting as return? a boolean or the founded item?

Comment: @Deniz I updated my question. I would want to search the array for the first item that matches the condition and return it. If no item is found, then search the array for the first item using the second condition. If no item matches, just return *undefined*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only looking for string values, you could do this:

```js
const animals = ['dog', 'bird', 'snake'];
const animalsToTry = ['cat', 'dog'];

let favoriteAnimal = animalsToTry.find(animal => animals.includes(animal));

console.log(favoriteAnimal); // 'dog'
```

And if you're looking to match objects based on a property:

```js
const animals = [{id: 'dog'}, {id: 'bird'}, {id: 'snake'}];

function findFirstMatchingAnimal(animals, animalIds) {
  for (let id of animalIds) {
    const animal = animals.find(a => a.id === id);
    if (animal) return animal;
  }
}

console.log(findFirstMatchingAnimal(animals, ['cat', 'dog']));    // { id: 'dog' }
console.log(findFirstMatchingAnimal(animals, ['bird', 'dog']));   // { id: 'bird' }
console.log(findFirstMatchingAnimal(animals, ['cow', 'monkey'])); // undefined
```

Comment: I updated my question a bit by adding 'cat' into the `animals` array. I would want to find the first matching item, then if it's not found, look for the next instead. Depending on the order of the `animals` array, this solution could return the incorrect animal. Ex: if the animals array was ['dog', 'cat'], it would return dog since it's first when I'd want to prioritize 'cat'.

Comment: @Josh no, it would return `cat` (ie. the first "animalToTry" which is present in "animals" - no matter the index)

Comment: My bad, I read the code wrong. I see that you're finding the item in `animalsToTry` instead of `animals` which would return the correct result. The only caveat with this though is that I would need to return the item from the `animals` array though. For brevity, I mistakenly omitted that the `animals` array would be an array of objects.

Comment: I'm sorry @blex, I've deleted my comment, and given you +1.

Comment: @Josh I included an example where it returns an object from the original array

Comment: This is a solid answer. I was hoping there was a more concise solution that didn't involve having a separate function, but this likely is as concise as it gets :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list of keys (`favourites`) is ordered from high to low "priority", you could iteratively find the `favouriteAnimal` from the list of `animals`,

```js
function findFavourite(animals, favourites) {
  // assume that `favourites` is ordered from highest to lowest "priority"

  for (const favourite of favourites) {
    if (animals.includes(favourite)) {
      return favourite;
    }
  }

  return null;
}

const animals = ['dog', 'bird', 'snake'];

console.log(findFavourite(animals, ['cat', 'dog']));  // 'dog'
console.log(findFavourite(animals, ['cat', 'bird', 'dog']));  // 'bird'
console.log(findFavourite(animals, ['cat', 'mouse']));  // null
```